# Formatear fecha en JavaScript C# ASP

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, mvc, date

### gracias por la ayuda de antemano, les platico:

Estoy intentando recuperar ciertos registros de mi base de datos, para ello tengo una tabla, al dar click en un ID especifico se tienen que llamar la información, retornarla del controlador y mostrarla en la vista, tal cual es IdRegistro, Nombre, Fecha Inicio, Fecha Fin, 
estos dos primeros se muestran sin problemas, el problema los tengo con las fechas, cabe mencionar que estoy usando **DatePicker** en estos campos para asignar fechas en caso de hacer un cambio al registro y guardarlos.

Como pueden ver en la imagen los datos están siendo almacenados en las variables, pero no se muestran, ¿podrían asesorarme para lograr que se muestren en la vista?

```
function abrirModal(IdRegistro) {
    // 1| Validar Datos
    var DatosIndexO = document.getElementsByClassName("DatosObligatorios");
    var DatosJSIndexO = DatosIndexO.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < DatosJSIndexO; i++) {
        DatosIndexO[i].parentNode.classList.remove("error");
    }

    // 2| Condicional para Agregar o editar
    if (IdRegistro == 0) {
        // Para agregar nuevo registro
        alert("Desde registro");
    } else {
        // Para editar un regstro existente

        alert("Desde editar");
        $.get("Periodo/RecuperarDatosPeriodo/?DatoID=" + IdRegistro, function (dataPeriodo) {
            document.getElementById("DatosModalID").value = dataPeriodo[0].IIDPERIODO;
            document.getElementById("DatosModalNombre").value = dataPeriodo[0].NOMBRE;
            document.getElementById("DatosModalFechaInDP").value = dataPeriodo[0].FECHAINICIO;
            document.getElementById("DatosModalFechaFinDP").value = dataPeriodo[0].FECHAFIN;

        });
    }
};
```

[image: Código Funcionando sin mostrar datos de fecha]

Comment: Lo más probable es que tengas que editar el formato en que están llegando las fechas

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, este es mi formato de mi controlador donde mando las fechas:  .Select(Indice => new { Indice.IIDPERIODO, Indice.NOMBRE, FECHAINICIO = ((DateTime)Indice.FECHAINICIO).ToShortDateString(), FECHAFIN = ((DateTime)Indice.FECHAFIN).ToShortDateString()}).ToList();

Comment: Estas usando DatePicker de Bootstrap?

Comment: Efectivamente, amigo muchas gracias, ya pude solucionar mi problema, al parecer eran problemas de cache con mi navegador :'), ya me anda corriendo todo, gracias por dedicar tiempo, por estar al pendiente de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.

Limpié la caché del navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]